# Can I say "at him" is a indirect object? How to judge the noun phrases to be a direct object and an indirect object?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I looked ***at him***.

"I" is a subject of the sentence.

"looked" is a predicate.

Can I say "at him" is a indirect object?  How to judge the noun phrases to be a direct object and an indirect object?

Comment: I tried to answer this wholistically. Check - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23870/are-these-two-sentence-the-same-what-are-the-nuances-in-these-two-scenario/23872#23872

Comment: @snailplane As what you said above, so what is sentence constituent of "to me" ?

Comment: *at him* is an indirect object. I think the sentence lacks the direct object. A direct object is the receiver of action within a sentence *generally* follows the verb.

Comment: @MaulikV. I wonder whether an indirect object should be existed with a direct object and without a direct object,there is no so-called indirect object.

Comment: @snailplane What about "He looked at me."? "at me" is a complement of "looked" ?

Comment: @snailplane  How to define "direct object" and "indirect object"?

Comment: In "I looked at him", "looked" is a *verb*. The *predicate* is "looked at him", within which "at" is a preposition. I would simply call "him" the *object*. It serves no useful purpose to classify "him" as a *direct object* here (it's certainly not a typical one anyway) and in general we don't classify anything as an ***indirect** object* except in contexts where there is also a ***direct** object*.

Comment: I believe that we can come up with at least two different analyses for the sentence. If we treated "look at" as a phrasal verb, then "him" would be the (direct) object of the verb "to look at". On the other hand, if we treated "look" as a verb, and "at" as a preposition, then this "look" wold be an intransitive verb, that is, it has no object. And in this case, if we wanted to say "him" is an object of anything, it would have to be the object of the preposition "at", which is perhaps not useful for learners at large. I'm fine with either analysis. Imo, sometimes, analysis is not very useful.

Comment: @Damkerng: Agreed. I really can't see what use it is to classify an object as *direct* or *indirect* unless it's relevant to distinguishing it from another (*indirect* or *direct*) object. And I don't know that I'd call OP's *look at* a "phrasal verb" either, although I would accept that as a useful classification for certain usages, such as *"I'll look at improving my answer" (=think carefully about)*, or *"She's not much to look at, but she's great in the sack" (=find visually attractive)*.

Answer (score 1):

OP's example has a [*subject*](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/a/What-Is-The-Subject-Of-A-Sentence.htm) (**I**), and a 3-word [*predicate*](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/a/What-Is-A-Predicate.htm) consisting of a [*verb*](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/verbterm.htm) (**looked**), a [*preposition*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/prepositions.htm) (**at**) and an [*object*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29) (**him**).

In this particular context, "direct" and "indirect" are not useful subcategories of "object". From [myenglishpages.com](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-direct-indirect-object.php#.U3yhkNJdV2E)...

> *A direct object answers the question "What?"
>
>    ...
>
>    An indirect object answers the question "To whom?" or "For whom?"*
>
> *An indirect object is the recipient of the direct object, or an otherwise affected participant in the event. There must be a direct object for an indirect object to be placed in a sentence.
>
>   In other words **an indirect object cannot exist without a direct object**.*

Answer (score 1):

Regarding whether this example uses a phrasal verb or not (a point brought up in comments), when I checked [looked at - definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+at) and [looked at - synonyms](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/look-at#look-at_2)

while **looked at** can be considered a phrasal verb, this usage is not likely.

The referenced links have many examples so I won't repeat them. Therefore in:

> I looked at him.

I would judge **looked** to be a intransitive verb.